# Как колоночная БД находит осуществляет поиск по номеру строки?

Tags: база-данных, nosql

В статье https://highload.today/kolonochnye-bazy-dannykh/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это кажется очень логичным и понятным, но не понятно одно, если мы отсортировали каждую колонку для быстрого поиска но нам нужно сделать запрос "select * where type = 2" мы нашли что это строка (2) теперь нам нужно вытащить все остальные колонки по строке 2 но т.к. они отсортированны уже каждая по своему значению нам придется перебирать все данные?

Comment: Я думаю, что в таких СУБД используется еще и физические индексы по номерам строк, где для каждой строки указано в каких блоках файлов колонок содержатся данные

Comment: Мне кажется автор сам запутался. Во всех других источниках пишут, что все столбцы отсортированы по первичному ключу.